# How to set Calendar according to Timezone

Tags: android, java-calendar

I want to make a Calendar according to Timezone. I tried to resolve the issue by surfing different queries but i can't. Now it pick mobile default time. If anyone have idea please help me. Timezone should be UK time.

I tried:

```
{
    Calendar c1;
    c1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"), Locale.UK);
    int hour = c1.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minutes = c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = c1.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int day = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

But it also returns System date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android calendar timezones dont work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170256/android-calendar-timezones-dont-work)

Comment: @AliAhmed it just return Time not date. I want to make a calendar according to uk, not getting mobile dates.

Comment: @SentinelTechnologies Have you tried setTimeZone on Calendar object?

Comment: @DhavalPatel yes but that also no working.

Comment: @SentinelTechnologies Can you post your code here?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. To understand what you need help with, please tell us what you have tried and in what way it failed. Since `setTimeZone` didn’t work, show us [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and specify precisely how observed behaviour differed from the expected. Also what your search brought up and what you’re still missing after having gone through that.

Comment: {
    Calendar c1;
    c1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"), Locale.UK);
    int hour = c1.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minutes = c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = c1.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int day = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}

But it also return System date

Comment: Thanks for the code. Please post it *in the question* (nicely formatted). You have an edit link under the question. It’s best to have everything in one place, and your code will also be readable. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

```
    ZonedDateTime nowInUk = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
    int hour = nowInUk.getHour();
    int minutes = nowInUk.getMinute();
    int seconds = nowInUk.getSecond();
    int day = nowInUk.getDayOfMonth();
    Month month = nowInUk.getMonth();
    int year = nowInUk.getYear();

    System.out.println("hour = " + hour + ", minutes = " + minutes + ", seconds = " + seconds 
            + ", day = " + day + ", month = " + month + ", year = " + year);
```

When I ran this snippet just now, it printed:

> hour = 3, minutes = 41, seconds = 15, day = 5, month = OCTOBER, year =
>   2018

`ZonedDateTime` largely replaces the outdated `Calendar` class.

### What went wrong in your code?

Time zone ID for UK time is `Europe/London`. In your code you used `UTC`, which is something else and wll give you a different result, at least sometimes. UK time coincides with UTC some of the year in some years, but not at this time of year this year. So you got a time that was one hour earlier than UK time.

Also `c1.get(Calendar.HOUR)` gives you the hour within AM or PM from 1 through 12, which I don’t think was what you intended.

### Question: Can I use `java.time` on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on new Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310, where the modern API was first described).
- On (older) Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. Make sure you import the date and time classes from package `org.threeten.bp` and subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Comment: V.V how to get  current time minimum sdk version of  26

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for get time from timezone but here is one condition must need  to checked auto time in setting's otherwise move to setting's page.

```
 private void setDateTime() {
//        Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 1);
        try {
            int value = Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME);
            if (value == 1) {
                Log.i("value", String.valueOf(value));
                {
                    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
                    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, new Locale("en", "in"));
                    String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
                    Log.i("get C_d_t", date);
                    txt_time.setText(date);
                }
            } else {
                //move to settings
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Must need to checked automatic date & time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS), 0);


            }
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: @OleV.V. TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));  time zone like this

Comment: After editing your code gives the correct output. I don’t think the locale makes any difference, and certainly the three-letter country code `ind` isn’t recognized. Changing the JVM’s default time zone may have consequences, and unwanted consequences, for other parts of your program and for other programs running in the same JVM.

Comment: @OleV.V. checked  en - in country code   has changed